# Can't update Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

Getting the following error

```
N: Ignoring file 'mono-official-stable.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type 'Executing:' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
N: Ignoring file 'mono-official-stable.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

This is a Nano emergency file where the buffer gets dumped on a SIGHUP, SIGTERM or if Nano runs out of memory. Provided your original file (`mono-official-stable.list`) looks fine then you can delete this - however the next error suggest that it might not be:

```
E: Type 'Executing:' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Here it's complaining that `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list` isn't in the correct format - more specifically it's found `Executing:` on line 1 which isn't understood.

My suggestion is that you compare `mono-official-stable.list` and `mono-official-stable.list.save.1` to work out what the correct format for `mono-official-stable.list` should be and then make the appropriate amends.

To give you an idea, my `mono-offical-stable.list` file contains the following 1 line:

```
deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-raspbianstretch main
```